# What is the flange focal distance of CS mount lenses? Is it 12.500 mm or 12.526 mm?

Tags: lens-mount, screw-mount

I've searched online a lot, and found plenty of sites that quote both numbers.

There appears to be agreement that the C-mount flange focal distance (FFD) is 17.526 mm (exactly 0.69 inches).

The CS-mount is either 5.0 mm less or 5.026 mm less.

Does anybody have a definitive answer?

Comment: why do you care

Comment: Why do I care? To know where to put the lens so it'll focus to infinity. (Whyever else?)

Answer (score 3):

CS mount is 5mm less than C mount.  However, there is no such thing as "exactly", and a 0.026mm difference isn't significant as long as lens elements can move far enough to focus.